# Тип byte в C++

Tags: c++

Интересует данный тип данных: вопрос в том, что вроде в исходниках (чужих) встречается, а у меня компилятор ругается на

```
   byte a;
   BYTE a;
```

Comment: Да, или используйте typedef.

Comment: а использование char не замедлит доступ к этой переменной?

Comment: @RoyTheCatxq *Поменьше думайте о скорости.* Лучше написать хороший качественный фрагмент кода, работающий в 10 раз медленнее, чем написать быстрый код, который невозможно поддерживать.

Comment: @RoyTheCatxq, а сами Вы считаете, что разные **слова**, обозначающие **одну и ту же сущность** заставят компилятор сгенерить разный код ?

Comment: Вроде char - символьный тип, по крайней мере при присвоение char целого числа, префиксный и постфиксный инкримент не работает.

Comment: С чего бы это? замечательно работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам совершенно правильно написали, что такого типа в C++ нет. И тем не менее в чужом коде встретить Вы его могли. Например, из [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> BYTE     
> A byte (8 bits).
> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
> typedef unsigned char BYTE;

Таким образом, в WinAPI-приложениях тип BYTE может встречаться, но раскрывается как unsigned char.

Comment: `typedef != макроподстановка`

Comment: Да, верно, я сначала нашел описание, где утверждалось, что этот тип вводится через #define, потом наткнулся на статью в MSDN. Спасибо, поправлю.

Answer (score 2):

В `c++17` появился тип `std::byte` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte.